# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [] in DispatcherServlet with name '

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

Morning, I already checked most of the answers to this problem ([No mapping found for HTTP request with URI.... in DispatcherServlet with name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683847/no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-in-dispatcherservlet-with-name)) and also ([No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ChickenTest/index] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845322/no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-chickentest-index-in-dispatcherser)) but I'm still getting "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/bmoa-surrounds/bmoa] in DispatcherServlet with name 'bmoa'", so, any help whould be apreciated:

pom:

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- Junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>    

        <!-- Log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

then my web.xml

```
<display-name>bmoa-surrounds</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/bmoa-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>bmoa</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>bmoa</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

my spring config file

```
<context:component-scan base-package="xxxx"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:spring-configured/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
```

and finally my controller

```
@Controller
public class BMOAServlet implements HttpRequestHandler {


    /**
     * 
     */
    @RequestMapping("/bmoa-surrounds/bmoa")
    public void handleRequest(final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {

         response.getWriter().write("result=" + handleIncomingMessage(request));
    }
```

I'm calling "http:// localhost :8080/bmoa-surrounds/bmoa?juan=9898" but I'm still geting No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/bmoa-surrounds/bmoa] in DispatcherServlet with name 'bmoa', any ideas? my env is java6 a deploying to jboss

also im sure that the beans are beign loaded, I got this in the server log

```
12:34:06,671 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (MSC service thread 1-5) Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@57ffa0: defining beans [BMOABussinesDelegate,properties,BMOAServlet,.........]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@122d7c6
```

and also this

```
12:34:06,753 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-5) Mapped URL path [/bmoa-surrounds/bmoa] onto handler 'BMOAServlet' 12:34:06,754 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-5) Mapped URL path [/bmoa-surrounds/bmoa.*] onto handler 'BMOAServlet' 12:34:06,755 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] (MSC service thread 1-5) Mapped URL path [/bmoa-surrounds/bmoa/] onto handler 'BMOAServlet'
```

doesnt the last one means that the mappings are loaded?? please help ;(

Comment: changed acording to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351777/no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-myappname-in-dispatcherservlet-wi?rq=1, my logfile changed: INFO  [RequestMappingHandlerMapping]  Mapped "{[/bmoa-surrounds/bmoa],... onto public void BMOAServlet.handleRequest(...) throws IOException
 but I'm still getting the same error WARN  [PageNotFound] No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/bmoa-surrounds/bmoa] in DispatcherServlet with name 'bmoa'

Comment: Change your servlet mapping url pattern to:  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>. Let me know how that goes

Comment: now it doesn't even load the index.jsp 12:58:01,667 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/bmoa-surrounds/bmoa] in DispatcherServlet with name 'bmoa'
12:58:01,943 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/bmoa-surrounds/index.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'bmoa'

Comment: Im guessing some miss configuration, because the log sais it has been mapped, the it says that theres no mapping :s

Comment: Does nobody care about [spring] anymore? [Almost 300 identical questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22No+mapping+found+for+HTTP+request+with+URI%22+%22in+DispatcherServlet+with+name%22). Where's the canonical duplicate? Or is Stack Overflow and content curation misunderstood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm feeling really dumb right now....at first (and thanks for the clue Angad), the url-pattern was wrong, it should point to the servlet, also, the loaded bean was BMOAServlet instead of bmoa, so when I changed the url-patter no bmoa, managed to see the error, at the end my web.xml needed to look like this:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/bmoa-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>bmoa</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>bmoa</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/bmoa</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

and the bean class like this:

```
@Controller("bmoa")
public class BMOAServlet implements HttpRequestHandler {



    /**
     * 
     */
    @RequestMapping("/bmoa-surrounds/bmoa")
    public void handleRequest(final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {

         response.getWriter().write("result=" + handleIncomingMessage(request));
    }
```

Now everything works smooth, I also changed the servlet class like this:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>bmoa</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this config file: src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\spring\appServlet\controllers.xml

content is like:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.samples.mvc" />
```

is your controller in "org.springframework.samples.mvc"?

Comment: yup those are there, actually I found the solution, I've just forgotten to mark as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

In pom.xml make sure packaging is set to `war` like `<packaging>war</packaging>` ,not to jar or any thing else.